# Arguments must not be initialized

Tags: c++, compilation

Is it possible to add a compiler-level constraint to function arguments that they must not already be initialized, e.g. the following would be okay:

```
void f(SomeClass& a) { /* ... */ }

int main() {
    f(new SomeClass());
    return 0;
}
```

While the following would NOT be okay: (since `a` is initialized and stored in a variable)

```
int main() {
    SomeClass a;
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. `f(new SomeClass());` is wrong on many levels. The pointer resulting from `new` *is* initialized

Comment: Other than one being allocated on the heap and the other being on the stack your two variables are the same and are both initialised

Comment: It sounds like you should forget about `new` and start looking into rvalue references and move semantics.

Comment: `new SomeClass()` returns value of type `SomeClass*`, not `SomeClass&`, and since there is no conversion possible between the two, such code wouldn't compile. In addition to that, it initializes the object itself in **the same manner** as `SomeClass a` does. Only the storage location/duration differs.

Comment: You could add a `bool initialized = false;` member variable in your class instance, and then set it to true when the object becomes initialized.  Useful for two-phase construct-then-initialize pattern (anti-pattern?).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, really? Why would passing lvalues be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading between the lines, is the goal to allow

```
f(g());
```

where `SomeClass g()` returns an object of type `SomeClass`?

And to not allow

```
SomeClass a;
f(a);
```

If that's it, then you're looking at rvalue references:

```
void f(SomeClass&& arg);      // argument is rvalue reference
void f(const SomeClass& arg); // argument is lvalue reference

f(g()); // calls f(SomeClass&&)
SomeClass a;
f(a);   // calls f(SomeClass&)
```

That can be defeated deliberately:

```
f(std::move(a)); // calls f(SomeClass&&)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a consideration regarding `*` and `&`. 
They are not the same. 
The function `new SomeClass()` returns a value `SomeClass*`which is different from `SomeClass&`. 
Therefore your code will not compile because there is no implicit conversion available.

Consider a new structure for your code like:

```
void f(SomeClass* a) { /* ... */ }

int main() {
SomeClass* a = new SomeClass();
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to work with "uninitialized" objects (or rather memory, because the object comes to life with the constructor call, which initializes it) is to write error-prone code that is closer to C than to C++. That's because the C++ type system tries hard to keep you away from uninitialized objects.

If you really want to go down this path, you would `malloc` an appropriate chunk of memory and pass that to `f`, which would then use [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to initialize the object in that memory. You could theoretically wrap this in another class that has these semantics.

Somewhat relatedly, there are standard containers that might somewhat fulfill what you want, but none have the primary semantics/purpose of holding "uninitialized" objects:

- `std::unique_ptr`:

  ```
  void f(std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>& a) { assert(!a); /* Initialize a... */ }

  std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> a; // a is empty
  f(a);
  ```
- `std::optional`:

  ```
  void f(std::optional<SomeClass>& a) { assert(!a.has_value()); /* Initialize a... */ }

  std::optional<SomeClass> a; // a is empty
  f(a);
  ```